# DataBinding in Anroid RecyclerView doesn't work (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-jetpack

Here's my OnBindViewHolder function code:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val country = countries[position]
    var countryInfoCardBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<CountryInfoCardBinding>(context as Activity, R.layout.country_info_card)
    countryInfoCardBinding.country = country
}
```

And here's my XML file:

https://pastebin.com/PySQFLmv

Comment: ...and what is the issue? "Hello, see my car, it doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inflate your data binding object in `onCreateViewHolder`, not `onBindViewHolder`. Now you're inflating an object which has no connection to your view, which is why (I'm assuming) nothing appears

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val country = countries[position]
    holder.binding.country = country
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val binding = CountryInfoCardBinding.inflate(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
        parent,
        false
    )

    return ViewHolder(binding)
}

inner class ViewHolder(val binding: CountryInfoCardBinding) : RecyclerView.Viewholder(binding.root)
```